# Passing char pointer into a function error

Tags: c, function, pointers, char

Hello I'm getting an error when i try to pass a char through to a function.
here is my code.

variable

```
char *temp;
```

Prototype

```
int checkIfUniqueCourseNo(char,int);
```

Call

```
checkIfUniqueCourseNo(temp,k);
```

and my error

```
warning: improper pointer/integer combination: arg #1
```

Im new to C so go easy on me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function accepts a `char`; you are trying to pass in a `char*`.

To fix this you need to [*dereference*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) your pointer to obtain the character that it points to, so that your function receives the type of argument it expects:

```
checkIfUniqueCourseNo(*temp,k);
```

Comment: @DanielDC - make sure you have a valid address in the pointer before dereferencing it (in your question you just declared it, but did not initialize it)

Answer (score 0):

If the function excepts `char`, you should dereference the pointer:

```
checkIfUniqueCourseNo(*temp,k);
//                    ^ pass the char addressed by temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is a `char*`(char pointer), but the function takes a `char`(not a pointer).

If you want to pass the *contents* of temp to the function, use `checkIfUniqueCourseNo(*temp, k)`. If you really do want to pass the pointer itself, declare the function as

```
int checkIfUniqueCourseNo(char*,int);
```